# New Alfresco 5 CE install fails on solr

Tags: alfresco

All,

I have just downloaded Alfresco 5 from the website and installed it on a new CentOS 6.5 server.
I'm using the buildin postgress database but I can't login due soir errors.

I have tried the installation several times but always the same error;

```
ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-3] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03030009 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1091)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:153)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Comment: SOLR errors won't stop you logging in, they'll only affect functionality when logged in. Is there anything else in your logs? Perhaps something explaining why the Alfresco webapp didn't deploy?

Comment: Stupid, stupid ..... Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: demo.xxx.local: unknown error I have forgotten the /etc/resolv